# Determine if reboot is required to update kernel?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, upgrade, reboot

I am running a server which runs on CentOS with cPanel (latest version) and I have it set to automatically update using yum. Since it needs to be rebooted in order to update the kernel (and possibly other things), I was wondering if there's any way to figure out if a reboot is required?

**EDIT:** The server is a VPS and it's running on OpenVZ. Because of the way OpenVZ works, there's no `/boot/vmlinuz` and `yum list installed kernel` doesn't work either.

Comment: OpenVZ slices **do not have their own kernel** and so there is no point in trying to update it.  The whole machine just runs one kernel belonging to the host system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following bash script from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/311733/175332) from ServerFault.

```
#!/bin/bash
LAST_KERNEL=$(rpm -q --last kernel | perl -pe 's/^kernel-(\S+).*/$1/' | head -1)
CURRENT_KERNEL=$(uname -r)

test $LAST_KERNEL = $CURRENT_KERNEL || echo REBOOT
```

Comment: as an answer - good, but as a solution - no, this will return REBOOT in case of a custom kernel installed/compiled, kernel is not installed, and other rpm names errors.

Comment: If a package is upgraded which required an upgrade in initrd, a reboot is required but it is the same kernel version.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we print out running kernel version:

```
# uname -r 
2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.i686

Ok, we have to patch:

# yum update kernel*

Grab the kexec tools:

# yum install kexec-tools

Now we get last installed kernel version release and put it on a var:

# latestkernel=`ls -t /boot/vmlinuz-* | sed "s/\/boot\/vmlinuz-//g" | head -n1` 

# echo $latestkernel 
2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.i686

Now we need to load the new kernel version in memory:

# kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz-${latestkernel} --initrd=/boot/initramfs-${latestkernel}.img --append="`cat /proc/cmdline`"

Finally, we can issue a reset:

# kexec -e

..and.. wow, we lost the system! ..Well, not exactly.

The system will “restart without restarting”..something like a fast reboot, without performing BIOS checks (and you know how long can a full system restart last).

# uname -r
2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.i686
```

It worked!

- Be aware that kernel reset will perform a connection reset as well, together with resetting your uptime, so if you’re searching for something to grant your uptime record while security patching, well, this is not for you.

Comment: I should've noted that it is a OpenVZ VPS and therefore /boot/vmlinuz doesn't exist. Is there anyway to get around that?

Comment: This question can be better answered in Ask Ubuntu.